# fesetround not affecting library functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio

VS 2015 building for x86-32, though I've seen this problem since .NET 2003.

I'm wondering why this hasn't been fixed:

```
#include <cfenv>
#include <cmath>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    auto y_lo = sin(1.0); // y_lo = 0.84147098480789650
    fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    auto y_hi = sin(1.0); // y_hi = (same)

    // y_hi SHOULD BE 0.84147098480789662

    return 0;
}
```

Stepping through the dissasembly for `sin` reveals that it resets the rounding mode before doing an `fsin` (why?). Besides re-writing all library functions by hand, what can be done to remedy this?

## EDIT:

Here's the offending `cmp` that checks the saved control word at `[esp]` - nothing fancy before it, just a `call`.

```
cmp         word ptr [esp],27Fh ; WTF? Why force a default here?
```

So, AFAIK, this little slice of brilliance (or something similar) has been festering in the CRT for at least 12 years. Has nobody noticed this? I can neither find or imagine any logical rationale behind this.